# Set proxy using google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build a chrome extension which can change proxy settings when the fire up the browser. I have followed the chrome extension documentation but still no success.

manifest.json

```
   {

      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Proxy",
      "description": "Proxy on 127.0.0.1:8080",
      "version": "1.1",
      "background": {
      "scripts":["background.js"]
      },
      "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "icon.png",
            "popup":"popup.html"
        },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "notifications",
        "contextMenus",
        "history",
        "background",
        "proxy"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
    }
```

backround.js

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {

var config = {
  mode: "fixed_servers",
  rules: {
    proxyForHttp: {
      scheme: "http",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port:"8080"
    },
    bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
  }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
    function() {});

});
```

The above code doesn't works...

Answer (score 3):

Change the line `port:"8080"` to `port:8080` and it'll work.

---

#### Nicety

You can check effective settings at chrome://net-internals/#proxy.

---

#### Nicety

If via PAC script, on script code error, `chrome.proxy.settings.set` handler still runs even as the proxy fails silently. This can be detected at chrome://net-internals/#events.

---

#### Nicety

[This page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy#TOC-How-do-I-debug-a-PAC-script-Why-can-t-I-see-the-alert-and-javascript-errors-it-gave-) claims that console.log messages in your PAC script can be found in net log, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nice tip of `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`!

Comment: How about adding "https" then?

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying everything since yesterday, finally found my issue; I had to change

`proxyForHttp:` --> `singleProxy:`

and

`port:'8080'` --> `port: 8080`

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem with the background page. Your code is in the onCreated event on the window object. You are not guaranteed to have the extension loaded by the time the first window is created.

Simply remvove the event and have the code run, you should then have it run once when the extension is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can use the chrome.proxy API from Background.js.
i did the same with a pop-up extension (used the code samples from the documentation) and it works perfectly...

Comment: It works from background.js. You need to refresh the extension after changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code ,chrome give me tips that the port num is to be integer ,but not string 
and change this 
port:"8080"
to 
port:8080,it worked
but i did not follow all of your codes, and delete this
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
,leaving only the contents in this function
3ks for your question!

Answer (score 0):

"when the fire up the browser"

You Should use [Chrome.Runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) instead chrome.windows.onCreated.
Use chrome.runtime.onStartup, So When Browser is open from nothing hrome.runtime.onStartup will fired.

> onStartup
>   Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up. This event is not fired when an incognito profile is started, even if this extension is operating in 'split' incognito mode.

It Will Be Like This

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
var config = {
  mode: "fixed_servers",
  rules: {
    proxyForHttp: {
      scheme: "http",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port:"8080"
    },
    bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
  }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
    function() {});

});
```

also you can use onInstalled for when you install / update the extension...

Comment: how do i use proxy for each new tab created or even update via postMessage. so can change proxies times in a tab.

Comment: @CodeCooker um... i think chrome didn't support that feature (proxy per tab), on chrome.proxy there isn't setting for each tab even on chrome browser. But you can setup proxies for each domain with pac script.